# Переданный параметр не записывается в таблицу

Tags: mvc, ruby

Есть 2 таблицы:

```
 1) class CreateTodos < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
 create_table :todos do |t|
 t.string :text
 t.boolean :isCompleted
 t.references :project, foreign_key: true
 t.timestamps
 end
 end
 end

  2) class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
  create_table :projects do |t|
  t.string :title
  t.timestamps
  end
  end
  end
```

Вот рауты

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
root 'projects#index'
resources :projects 
resources :todos
end
```

Вот код с контроллерами

projects_controller:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

      # GET /projects
      # GET /projects.json
      def index
        @projects = Project.all
      end

      # GET /projects/1
      # GET /projects/1.json
      def show
      end

      # GET /projects/new
      def new
        @project = Project.new
      end

      # GET /projects/1/edit
      def edit
      end

      # POST /projects
      # POST /projects.json
      def create
        @project = Project.new(project_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @project.save
            format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Задача добавлена.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # PATCH/PUT /projects/1
      # PATCH/PUT /projects/1.json
      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @project.update(project_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Задачи обновлены.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # DELETE /projects/1
      # DELETE /projects/1.json
      def destroy
        @project.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to projects_url, notice: 'Project was successfully destroyed.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_project
          @project = Project.find(params[:id])
        end

        # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def project_params
          params.require(:project).permit(:title)
        end
    end
```

todos_controller:

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController
        before_action :set_todo, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

        # GET /todos
        # GET /todos.json
        def index
          @todos = Todo.all
        end

        # GET /todos/1
        # GET /todos/1.json
        def show
        end

        # GET /todos/new
        def new
          @todo = Todo.new
        end

        # GET /todos/1/edit
        def edit
        end

        # POST /todos
        # POST /todos.json
        def create
          @todo = Todo.new(todo_params)

          respond_to do |format|
            if @todo.save
              format.html { redirect_to @todo, notice: 'Todo was successfully created.' }
              format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @todo }
            else
              format.html { render :new }
              format.json { render json: @todo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
          end
        end

        # PATCH/PUT /todos/1
        # PATCH/PUT /todos/1.json
        def update
          respond_to do |format|
            if @todo.update(todo_params)
              format.html { redirect_to @todo, notice: 'Todo was successfully updated.' }
              format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @todo }
            else
              format.html { render :edit }
              format.json { render json: @todo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
          end
        end

        # DELETE /todos/1
        # DELETE /todos/1.json
        def destroy
          @todo.destroy
          respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to todos_url, notice: 'Todo was successfully destroyed.' }
            format.json { head :no_content }
          end
        end

        private
          # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
          def set_todo
            @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
          end

          # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
          def todo_params
            params.require(:todo).permit(:text, :isCompleted, :project_id)
          end
      end
```

View с формой

```
<div class="form-box">
 <div class="form-box-wrapper">
  <%= form_with scope: :todo, url: todos_path, local: true do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :text, placeholder: 'Название задачи' %>
  <%= select(:post, :project_id, Project.all.collect{|p| [ p.title, p.id ] }, {include_blank: 'None'}) %>
  <br>
  <%= form.submit %>
  <a href="/" id="candel_button" class="cansel">ОТМЕНА</a>
  <% end %>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Код моделей

```
class Todo < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :project, optional: true
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :todos
end
```

Все контроллеры были созданы через scaffold, поэтому их код стандартный.
Возник вопрос, из формы передаются параметры на добавление в таблицу, во 2 таблицу, в консоли все параметры верны, но id из 1 таблиц не записывается во 2. Буду благодарен за ответ, заранее спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ян, было бы здорово всё-таки в каждом вопросе предоставлять весь код, относящийся к нему. Если бы вы просто обновили предыдущий вопрос и добавили туда модели и формы, было бы гораздо удобнее.

Я так понимаю, сейчас у вас в TodosController что-то вроде

```
def create
  @todo = Todo.new(todo_params)
  if @todo.save
    redirect_to @todo
  else
    render :edit
  end
end

private

def todo_params
    params[:todo].permit(:text, :project_id)
end
```

Для того, чтобы это работало, форма должна передать все параметры под ключом `todo`, у вас же project_id находится (внезапно) под ключом `post`. Правильная форма будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
<div class="form-box">
  <div class="form-box-wrapper">
    <%= form_with model: @todo, local: true do |form| %>
    <%= form.text_field :text, placeholder: 'Название задачи' %>
    <%= form.select(:project_id, Project.all.collect{|p| [ p.title, p.id ] }, {include_blank: 'None'}) %>
    <br>
    <%= form.submit %>
    <a href="/" id="candel_button" class="cansel">ОТМЕНА</a>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Соответственно, в new/edit экшнах у вас должна быть определена переменная  @todo, скаффолд должен был справиться с этим.

Comment: я добавил код контроллеров. Исправил строчку с form_with, как Вы и написали, но теперь, если посмотреть код элементов в браузере, то action в форме стал равен "/". В контроллере переменная "@todo" определена.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрал:) Ответ с формой оставил в предыдущем вопросе.

Comment: Отлично, рада была помочь :)